# Python, print all files in a directory (including those in sub folders)

Tags: python, file, operating-system

I am attempting to create a python desktop assistant, on of the roles is to print out any files matching the user's input. This works, but does not extract from folders within the parent directory.

```
def run():
p("Please enter file name\n")
a = input('> ')
import glob, os
os.chdir("H:/")
for file in glob.glob(a+'.*'):
    print(file)
```

Comment: your pattern includes an extension (because of the '.*'), so it would ignore directories. Do you mean that you want the search to be recursive inside folders and subfolders?

Comment: you could use this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964681/find-all-files-in-directory-with-extension-txt-in-python

Comment: That's how I got the orginal code, but it wasn't searching in any sub folders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing you want to print all files that contain an input string:

```
def run():
    match_this = raw_input('Please enter string to match > ')

    for dirpath, _, filenames in os.walk('H:\\'):
        for filename in filenames:
            if match_this in filename:
                print os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
```